# Viewing and Transfering files between Nexus 7 (13) and Win 7sp1 x64

Tags: nexus-7, file-transfer

Having difficulty with both USB and wifi file transfers.  I recently upgraded my desktop from XP to Win7, all was working well with XP.

Over wifi ES file explorer sees the shared Win7 HDDs but will not open them to view contents.  Permissions on the HDDs are set to allow all users full access.
From the Win7 end the Nexus7 does not show at all on the LAN.

Connecting USB and using ES file explorer I don't know how to make the Win7 PC accessible.
In Win7 explorer the Nexus7 shows up and when Nexus7 USB for file transfers is selected most folders and files are accessible.  The exception are uTorrent down loaded files, why are these not accessible?

If anyone can help with file transfers or provide edifying links it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this answer to access Android Devices' files over a PC. 
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/42703/21342

You don't have to download any other application to start an FTP Server on your device, simply go to Remote Manager in Tools and press Start.

Make sure that both the phone and PC are on the same network.